# System.EntryPointNotFoundException: ''Gdi32.dll' DLL'sinde 'CreateRoundRecRgn' not found'

Tags: c#

I am trying to round corners of my Winform. Although i installed gdi32.dll i am getting an error like System.EntryPointNotFoundException: ''Gdi32.dll' DLL'sinde 'CreateRoundRecRgn' not found. Is there any way to round corner problem without dlls or how can i solve this problem ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;



namespace UI
{
    public partial class UI : Form


    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRecRgn")]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
            (
            int nLeftRect,          //x-coordiane of upper-left corner
            int nTopRect,           //y-coordiane of upper-left corner
            int nRightRect,         //x-coordiane of upper-left corner
            int nBottomRect,        //x-coordiane of lower-right corner
            int nWidthEllipse,      //x-width of ellipse
            int nHeightEllipse     //x-height of ellipse


            );
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleObject")]
        private static extern bool DeleteObject(System.IntPtr hObject);

        int TogMove;
        int MValX;
        int MValY;

        public UI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            System.IntPtr ptr = CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, 50, 50);
            this.Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(ptr);
            DeleteObject(ptr);

        }
```

Comment: You have typos in the `EntryPoint` property of both of your `DllImport` attributes.

Comment: I fix " DeleObject " but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have Naming Issue "CreateRoundRecRgn" change to this "CreateRoundRectRgn"

Comment: Its ok here is entry point list http://www.softspecialists.com/library/genlib/vistasp1/gdi32.htm you can find your entry points